# Managing navigation views on the stack

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

Being new to iPhone development I am really struggling with this concept. I have built an App which is not quite running the way that it should. I have a TabBar app. The secondViewController is essentially a form which I use to collect information about daily exercise. I have embedded this secondViewController into a Navigation controller so that I can push to a datePicker view and return with the date. I also push to a pickerView for exercise type and return with data. At least this is the intended process. I use the prepareForSegue to push the picker views and return to the secondViewController carrying data between them with each segue.

What I find is happening is that instead of pushing to the picker views and returning to the secondViewController my app seems to progress in a linear fashion. To be more precise it seems to push to the date picker, then push to a new 'instance' of the secondViewController, then push to pickerView, and then to another new instance of secondViewController. This means that when my users eventually touch the save button, they have to use the back button in the navBar to get back to the original secondViewController.

[Have an image to add but can't post it as I have reputation under 10 :-( ]

I have read Apple's documentation on managing the stack and hierarchy, but I just seem to have confused myself more than anything else. I have also searched for answers and tutorials, but I am either missing something or there is no clear explanation of how this is supposed to work that I can find. Can anyone tell me how to push to a pickerView and then return, or at least to return programmatically to the original secondViewController when the save button is finally touched?

Comment: It's going to be difficult to unconfuse you without some code...

Comment: Thanks Caleb, but what would you like to see? My prepareForSegue code or something from the header files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go Back in hierarchy in UINavigation Controller you can use

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, but where do I use this? Is it part of the prepareForSegue?

Comment: prepareForSegue is used before the new viewController is pushed onto the stack (into view). So use popViewControllerAnimated can be used anytime you want to close/pop off the current view controller. For instance, you could use it in the current visible viewControler to pop it out of view/off the stack.